# Tor browser downloading MPEG-4 videos instead of playing them

Tags: help

a pop up window shows up asking what to do with the file instead of playing it in the browser.

I just reinstalled tor and before the reinstallation it worked just fine

Comment: Can you show a screenshot? It would make it easier for us to help.

Comment: there might be an option in Tor settings for what to do when clicking on video files, similar to Firefox. Let me know when you find it

Comment: Are you saving the files instead of viewing them? Check the Files and Application section in about:preferences.